# Добавление пунктов меню Jquery contextMenu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В процессе выполнения одного задания столкнулся с проблемой, масштаб которой мне трудно оценивать. Обращусь с вопросом сюда. Используя плагин Jquery contextMenu мне нужно написать некую функцию, которая бы добавляла пункты меню количественно, конкретное количество зависит от числа в input type="number". То-есть, после того, как в input будет какое-то число, открывая контекстное меню, количество пунктов меню
соответствовало этому числу.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.input-with-context-menu', 
        callback: function(key, options) {
            var m = "clicked: " + key;
            window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
        },
        items: {
            "blank": {name: "Blank", icon: "meh-blank"},
            "sep1": "---------",
            "finish": {name: "Применить", icon: function(){
                return null;
            }}
        }
    });

    $('.input-with-context-menu').on('click', function(e){
        console.log('clicked', this);
    })    
});
```

Данный пример является стандартным примером в документации плагина, кроме пары имён. В этой же документации не нашёл создания пунктов в меню "на ходу", только прописывание этих самых пунктов заранее.

Comment: переинициализировать плагин ? По клику на кнопку разрушить, и инициализировать с нужным кол-м. вроде в доке есть $.contextMenu( 'destroy' ); . $.contextMenu хавает обьект в параметр, можно соствить его отдельно в функции и отдать ему

Comment: @Crus А есть какой-то более глупый способ а-ля contextMenu.item add, или что-то в этом роде?

Comment: не работал с этой либой, не подскажу )